# How to remove selection-marker from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I like my websites to be beautiful. And I'm quite obsessive-compulsive about certain things. I need/want to remove the ugly dotted lines from the border of images upon clicking them. I don't want them to be visible. Dotted lines be gone!

Is this possible? Maybe with some javascript or jQuery?

Any help at all is appreciated.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
a { outline: 0; } /* CSS Code */
```

Comment: What a magical guess that was!